# Getting Primary ID on clicking a List Item in Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview

I am trying to create a list view for a password manger which will populate a listview with items from Database and when someone clicks it will return the primaryid.... I have seen other examples but not able to get it done corectly.... Here's what I have done so far.... I am able to Populate the List View but not able to handle on click events :(

```
    ArrayList<String> listItems=new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice , listItems);


    SQLiteDatabase DB= null;
     final String TableName = "XIBEAT_PASSWORDS";
     String DBname="Xibeat_Crypto_Knight_Vault";
    try {
        DB = this.openOrCreateDatabase(DBname, MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        DB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TableName + " ('_id' INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,HOST TEXT, URL TEXT, PASSWORD TEXT, NOTES TEXT, TAG TEXT, TIME TEXT, DATE TEXT, EXPIRE TEXT, EDITED TEXT, STRENGTH TEXT, REASON TEXT);");


           Cursor c = DB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TableName , null);

           int host= c.getColumnIndex("HOST");

           String title="";
           c.moveToFirst();
        if(c!=null)
        {
        while (c.moveToNext()){
                    title = c.getString(host);
                    //Toast(title);
                    listItems.add(title);

        }
        }  

        final ListView passList=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.passlist);
        passList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems));
        //===============ONCLICK LISTENER+=========
        passList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
        {public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3) {






        }});            





          } finally {
           if (DB != null)
            DB.close();
          }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are reading data from a `Cursor`, you should be using a [CursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html) or one of its subclassses such as [SimpleCursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html)  in place of `ArrayAdapter`:

```
Cursor c = DB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TableName , null);
final ListView passList=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.passlist);
passList.setAdapter(new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, // Context
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, // Layout
    c, // Your Cursor
    new String[] { "HOST" }, // Column(s) you want to display
    new int[] { android.R.id.text1 }),
    0); // Flags, 0 -> don't auto-requery when the data changes
```

The full signature for [`onItemClick`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html#onItemClick%28android.widget.AdapterView%3C?%3E,%20android.view.View,%20int,%20long%29) is:

> onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id)

If you use a `CursorAdapter`, then the last parameter, `id`, is the `_id` column in your database.

Comment: Thanks a lot man.... I owe you :)

Done Half way... I am able to get the Position in my SQLite database :) Quick QUestion... Since my _id is a autoincrement will it return the same _id for example:
for example if there are three items and I delete the second row from database... then I select the last element from the row.... will I get the ID as 3 or 2

Comment: Auto-increment columns don't reuse deleted _ids so you'll continue to get 3 for C (and if you insert D, it'll get _id 4, etc).

Comment: Man... It works on Galaxy S with Froyo... but fails to work on Nexus 7 with jellybean as it is deprecated.... Can you suggest me a way to do with CursorLoader :(

Comment: @user2937922 - CursorLoader would be a bigger conversion - you can use the non-deprecated constructor which adds a 'flag' parameter (which you can use `0` for) - I've updated my answer with that in mind.

Comment: Thanks for your Reply but I already tried that.... The app simply crash in 4.3 when I set the flag as 0... Trying to google... to get it done using Loaders :(

Comment: If it crashes, then what is the exception?

Comment: Got it done... actually, I was trying to query a empty database :p.... thanks a lot for your Help... but I guess I have to use the support Library for my Galaxy S 2.2 Froyo

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom List adapter that saves the Id (getColumnIndex("_id");) in your custom object instead of having Android create the simple view for you.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to use ArrayAdapter to load from DB. You should use CursorAdapter and CursorLoader to manage database instead. SimpleCursorAdapter is deprecated.

Here's a good tutorial on custom CursorAdapter: [link](http://www.gustekdev.com/2013/05/custom-cursoradapter-and-why-not-use.html?showComment=1392178404935#c3113158617968581957)

Another one for CursorLoaders: [link](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/07/loaders-and-loadermanager-background.html)